# Why use message queue with Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am reading about when to use node, and I see that an advantage of the non-blocking nature of node is  that it doesn't block the rest of the code and the other requests with I/O operations that take some time, and I understand this happens by sending these operations to the event loop.

My question is why do I need to use another message queue service that would do the same functionality of the event loop?

The part I'm confused with is "Queued Input" section here : [Why the hell would I use Node JS](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js)

Comment: RabbitMQ is a MessageBroker for interprocess- /interdevice communication. The EventQueue is a Concurrency model inside a nodejs engine. They don't have anything to do with each other ...

Comment: @derpirscher I'm confused why did the author of the article mentioned it as a solution ?

Comment: Because in that described scenario (heavy load on the database) there are two different processes running on the server: One for communicating with the client, one for communicating with the database. And RabbitMQ (or any other messagebroker) can be used for communication between these two processes.

Comment: The use of a message broker only becomes clear when you have a distributed system architecture where instead of one giant application you have many small components that makes up the entirety of the application. In such systems, communication between each component (aka services) can't be done in synchronous manner since there can be many services that need to coordinate among themselves. A broker like RabbitMQ, Kafka, SNS helps alleviate this problem and create eventual consistency across the system. To better appreciate these patterns you should read about Microservices.